# how to I use FileResult for download files from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make View Download but I always get error, Can someone fix this

this for my RazorView

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Upload</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Download", "download", "Home")</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and this for my controller

```
    public FileResult download(string fileName)
    {
        return File("~/App_Data/uploads", "multipart/form-data", fileName);
    }
```

I always get error after I click download in my View, can someone fix my code please..

this for my upload controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(updown viewModel, HttpPostedFileBase model)
    {
        // extract only the filename
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName);

        // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);

        try
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("uploadError", "Duplicate Data");
            }
            else
            {
                Request.Files[0].SaveAs(path);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("uploadError", "Can't save file to disk");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // put your logic here
            updown item = new updown();
            item.upload = fileName;
            db.updowns.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: `"~/App_Data/uploads"` is your folder not the file you want to download

Comment: And you question needs to state what the error is!

Comment: Your `download` action expects a `fileName` but your action link does not set one.

Comment: `~/App_Data/uploads` is a relative path, not actual file name. Use `Server.MapPath` pointing to actual file name to describe file path.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not a good way to use `FilePathResult`:

```
return File("~/App_Data/uploads", "multipart/form-data", fileName);
```

The correct [`FilePathResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult(v=vs.118).aspx) constructor to download file should be like this:

```
public FilePathResult(string fileName, string contentType, string fileDownloadName)
```

What you can do to fix it is retrieve the correct path of file location, then set proper content type (i.e. MIME type) & return `FilePathResult` like this:

```
public FileResult Download(string fileName)
{
    // other stuff

    // read all contents from source file
    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/"), fileName);

    // set content type, e.g. 'application/pdf' for PDF files
    // or use 'System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames' to get predefined content types
    string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(path);

    // return FilePathResult to download
    return File(path, contentType, fileName);
}
```

Then, set `ActionLink` to your controller action with `fileName` parameter like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", "Home", new { fileName = Model.FileName }, null)
```

NB: `Model.FileName` is a viewmodel property where you can assign file names from uploaded files, depending on viewmodel configuration.

Similar issue:

[Download File from FileSystem no matter the file type in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291561/download-file-from-filesystem-no-matter-the-file-type-in-mvc)

Comment: Is there a similar way that we can download static files in .Net Core 2.X, where my files are present inside wwwroot --> Templates--> sample.xlsx